# filter is not working for third child level (nested level)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to filter an array having nested level of 3.. I have to filter this array at the last level.

```
array = [{
    children: [{
        children: [{
            children: [],
            id: 2694,
            name: "Some Random data"
        }, {
            children: [],
            id: 2695,
            name: "Another Random Data"
        }],
        id: 2574,
        name: "Test data",
    }],
    id: 2530,
    name: "Main Test data"
}, {
    children: [{
        children: [{
            children: [],
            id: 2696,
            name: "Secondary test Data"
        }, {
            children: [],
            id: -1,
            name: "Random Text"
        }],
        id: 2575,
        name: "Another random Text"
    }],
    id: 2531,
    name: "New Data"
}]
```

I have tried this function

```
function(random){

let array3=[];
this.array.forEach(cap=>{
     let tempparent={...cap};
     let child1= tempparent.children.forEach(ch=>{
       let tempfeat={...ch};
       let tempchildren = tempfeat.children.filter(fe=>{
        if(fe.id!=random.id){
          return fe
        }
       });
     //  console.log(tempchildren)
       tempfeat.children = tempchildren;
     //  console.log(tempfeat.children)
     });
     console.log(child1)
     tempparent.children= child1;
     console.log(tempparent.children)
     nodes3.push(tempparent)
   })
   this.array= array3
   console.log(this.array);
}
```

I want to filter it at third level using id value. when the id matches the matched object must be removed.

Comment: i want to filter it at third level using id value. when the id matches the matched object must be removed

Comment: please add the wanted result to the question along with the error, you get.

Comment: or can we filter the complete nested array by id.. if id matches matched object must be removed

Comment: i want the result as whenever id matches the matched id object must be removed from given array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a dynamic approach and take the children out of the object, check the `id` and if found, ignore the object.

Otherwise take the children and get a subset with a recursive call and rebuild a new object and push this one to the result set.

This approach does not mutate the original data, but returns all new objects and works for an arbitrary count of levels.

```js
function remove(array, id) {
    return array.reduce((r, { children, ...o }) => {
        if (o.id === id) return r;
        children = remove(children || [], id);
        if (children.length) o.children = children;
        r.push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);
}

var data = [{ children: [{ children: [{ children: [], id: 2694, name: "Some Random data" }, { children: [], id: 2695, name: "Another Random Data" }], id: 2574, name: "Test data", }], id: 2530, name: "Main Test data" }, { children: [{ children: [{ children: [], id: 2696, name: "Secondary test Data" }, { children: [], id: -1, name: "Random Text" }], id: 2575, name: "Another random Text" }], id: 2531, name: "New Data" }],
    result = remove(data, 2574);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer.. when i tried to replicate the answer in angular 6 i'm getting error at 4th line of your code at remove... saying cannot find name remove...

Comment: did you take the function?

Comment: I did and made few changes as per my requirement.. its working perfect... thanks  for the answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive function.

For example, like this

```
function removeById(_id,arr){
    if(arr.id === _id){
    return true;
  }else{
    arr.children.forEach(currentItem => {
        if(getById(_id,currentItem)){
            arr.children = arr.children.filter(x=>x.id !== _id);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

and using this function

```
removeById(2694,array[0]);
removeById(2694,array[1]);
```

please examine [example](https://jsfiddle.net/hybersoar/mfw9o845/)